# PHP Uncaught ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, mysql

He estado tratando de actualizar mi tabla usando PHP, pero dicha tabla no se actualiza debido al error uncaught ArgumentCountError, el código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'] ?? "";

if($codigo){
    include 'conexion.php';
    if($conexion){
        
        $consulta="update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? and cantidad=?";
        if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$consulta)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$codigo,$cantidad);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $output="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
            }else{
                $output="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
            }    
        }else{
            $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
        
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        $output="No hay conexion";
    }
}else{
    $output="Codigo vacio o no valido";
}

echo $output;
?>
```

La idea de la consulta sería poder eliminar un item especifico del listado

Comment: En el mensaje de error te debe indicar la línea del error, ¿Cuál es?

Comment: El error se encuentra en esta linea:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$codigo,$cantidad);

Comment: Prueba indicando el tipo de dato de la segunda variable que pasas a dicho método, ya que son dos pero solo estás pasando uno

Comment: Probé a cambiar el tipo de dato de la segunda variable pero no me actualiza la tabla, es decir que me dice "Filas actualizadas: 0", cabe aclarar que la linea quedó de la siguiente manera: mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"si",$codigo,$cantidad);

Comment: Esa ya es una duda distinta, lo cual indica que el problema inicial ya se corrigió

Comment: Si el código te dice: `Filas actualizadas: 0` significa que han podido ocurrir dos cosas: 1. Que estés intentando actualizar seteando valores similares a los ya existentes; 2. Que no hay filas que cumplan con el criterio `WHERE` de la consulta...

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que estoy intentando hacer es eliminar un registro que tenga un código repetido pero diferente cantidad, por ejemplo dos item con código e5, uno con cantidad 2 y otro con cantidad 8, y yo por ejemplo quiero poder eliminar uno de esos dos item sin terminar eliminando los 2 al mismo tiempo

Comment: Pues en primer lugar, tu código está basado en una consulta `UPDATE` que lo que haría sería actualizar la fila. Si lo que quieres es borrarla tendrías que usar una consulta `DELETE`

Comment: Mi idea es hacerlo con UPDATE no con DELETE, en caso de que el campo sea 1, aparece en el listado, pero si es 0, se "elimina" del listado, y por ende no aparece